# How to select distinct years from DateTime with Peewee

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I've created a MySQL table with these fields:

```
id - int - auto_increment
dt - DateTime 
desc - VARCHAR 255
```

Now I would like know know how to select only the years from this table with Peewee in Python. Equal years should be removed.

In SQL I would simply do `SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(dt) AS yr from data;` to get the desired result.

I'm aware of the `db.execute_sql` method to execute a raw SQL-query. I wonder however if there is a cleaner way.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
query = Data.select(Data.dt.year.distinct())
for distinct_ts, in query.tuples():
    print(distinct_ts)
```

To sort by date:

```
distinct_ts = Data.dt.year.distinct()
query = Data.select(distinct_ts.alias('timestamp')).order_by(distinct_ts)
for row in query:
    print(row.timestamp)
```